# How to prove that if c is an odd integer that divides the sum and the difference of two integers a and b, then c divides both a and b?

Tags: number-theory, solution-verification

I have two questions regarding this. I'm new to proving so these may seem silly.

1. Is it better to prove directly or by using its contrapositive? Directly, I could prove by applying a bit of algebra and using its contrapositive, I have to show that c does not divide a or c does not divide b would give c does not divide their sum and difference. I hope this is correct.
2. Does c being odd have anything to do with the proof? If yes, how do I show it in the proof? Because when I try proving using c as any integer, I'm getting my answer.

Comment: "*when I try proving using $c$ as any integer, I'm getting my answer*" $\;-\;$ How so? For example $2$ divides $3+1$ and $3-1$ but it divides neither $3$ nor $1$.

Comment: Note that $c=2$  divides the sum and difference of *any* two odd integers, but does not divide either of them. So you definitely need the assumption that $c$ is odd.

Comment: I honestly do not understand the lone **Close Vote**.  Is the context not clear enough for those who ought to know better?  The OP gave his/her sincere thoughts regarding the problem.  What more could you ask for?

Answer (score 4):

$c$ being odd will be important to the proof. Here is a counter if $c=2$ and $a$, $b$ are odd, then $a+b, a-b$ are even, but $c$ doesn't divided $a$ or $b$.

Here is a direct proof. $c$ divides $a+b$ means that there exist an integer $k_1$ such that $a+b = k_1 c$. Similarly there exists an integer $k_2$ such that $a-b = k_2c$. Adding both equations together, we get that $2a = (k_1+k_2)c$. Now $c$ is odd, however, $2a$ is even, Thus we must have that $k_1+k_2$ is even. Thus $a = \frac{(k_1+k_2)}{2}c$ where $\frac{(k_1+k_2)}{2}$ is an integer.

Now if $c$ hadn't been odd, then we could have had that $k_1+k_2$ was odd, then $\frac{(k_1+k_2)}{2}$ wouldn't have been an integer.

So now $a = k_3c$. Then using $a+b = k_1c$, we see that $b = (k_1-k_3)c$. Thus, $c$ divides $a$ and $b$.

Answer (score 3):

I think it is best to prove this **directly**.

Suppose that $c$ is odd, and that $c \mid (a + b)$ and $c \mid (a - b)$ where both $a$ and $b$ are integers.

Let $A = a + b$ and $B = a - b$.  Then we obtain
$$\Bigg((c \mid A) \text{ and } (c \mid B)\Bigg) \implies \Bigg(c \mid (A + B) = 2a\Bigg).$$
Now, since $c$ is odd, $\gcd(c,2)=1$, which implies that $c \mid a$.

We also obtain, similarly,
$$\Bigg((c \mid A) \text{ and } (c \mid B)\Bigg) \implies \Bigg(c \mid (A - B) = 2b\Bigg).$$
Now, since $c$ is odd, $\gcd(c,2)=1$, which implies that $c \mid b$.

---

We therefore conclude that $c$ divides both $a$ and $b$.

Comment: This proof shows why the condition "$c$ is odd" is important in order for your argument to work, @J'sandK's.

Comment: What do you mean by $c|(A+B)=2a$? To me this statement is not well-defined; $2a\in \mathbb{Z}$, and $c|(A+B)$ is a relation which is either true or false, so I don't see how it makes sense to compare them using '='

Comment: @Joe:  Thank you for your feedback.  It is just shorthand for $c \mid (A+B)$, but since $A + B = 2a$, then $c \mid 2a$.  (So this is stated more compactly as $c \mid (A+B) = 2a.$)

Comment: Is this notation standard in number theory?

Answer (score 2):

From a linear algebra perspective, the basic reason for this is that $a+b$ and $a-b$ form a basis for the span of $a$ and $b$. If we take $u=a+b$ and $v=a-b$, then $a=\frac{u+v}2$ and $b=\frac{u-v}2$. So we can restate the claim as "If $c$ is an odd integer that divides both $u$ and $v$, then $c$ divides both $\frac{u+v}2$ and $\frac{u-v}2$".

This statement is easy to prove: divisibility is closed under addition and subtraction (that is, a multiple of $c$ plus or minus another multiple of $c$ is also a multiple of $c$). And since $c$ is odd, we don't have to worry about dividing by $2$; if $u+v$ is divisible by $c$, then so is half of $u+v$.